# logstash and elasticsearch missing data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I have this logstash configuration file and the query returns 10547 but in elasticsearch are just seen 10500.
Bigger data produce more loss obviously.

Why?

```json
input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://outsystemsdemomysql.cxxhlwetgta3.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/outsystems1"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "xxxxx"
        jdbc_password => "xxxxx"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.ID,
 CASE WHEN OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.NAME='' THEN 'Unknown' ELSE OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.NAME END name,
OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.TITLE,OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.PHONE,OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.ADDRESS,OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.EMAIL,OSUSR_QP0_ORGANIZATIONTYPE.AKA OrgType
FROM OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT
LEFT JOIN OSUSR_qp0_Organization ON (OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.ORGANIZATIONID=OSUSR_qp0_Organization.ID)
LEFT JOIN OSUSR_QP0_ORGANIZATIONTYPE ON (OSUSR_qp0_Organization.TYPE=OSUSR_QP0_ORGANIZATIONTYPE.ID)
WHERE  OSUSR_QP0_CONTACT.ARCHIVED = 0"
    }
}
output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => ["search-prochamps-nzv5olnw2mloxwiqd7s3o557we.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
        region => "us-east-1"
        # aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key optional if instance profile is configured
        aws_access_key_id => "xxxxx"
        aws_secret_access_key => "xxxx"
        index => "crm"
        document_type => "contacts"
        document_id => "%{id}"

    }


}
```

Comment: To debug that kind of issues, I am using two differents solutions:

 1. Using logstash in debug mode, even if it is not always clear to see what are the failed request.

 2. Using a local elasticsearch as another output for the logstash in order to see what are the failures through the logs.

Comment: How to use the logstash in debug mode? Another strange thing it is the fact that if i added the code 

stdout { codec => rubydebug }

all the data is posted

Comment: I use the --debug option when launching logstash /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --debug

Answer (score 0):

Try some debugging:

- use a stdout{} output in logstash and see how many documents are processed by it.
- check the logstash and elasticsearch logs to see if any errors were reported (e.g. a type mismatch in your mapping will cause dropped records).